# Windows IoT Scheduled Task not running

Tags: powershell, raspberry-pi, scheduled-tasks, windowsiot, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to create a scheduled task for Windows IoT on Raspberry Pi to run on boot to check the time on an real time clock hat and then set the system time accordingly. For context, see: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1113626/Adding-the-Missing-Real-Time-Clock-to-Windows-IoT.

I have a PS script that runs the following:

```
$CurrentDate = ( c:\shares\boot\SetTimeTool.exe )  |Out-String
set-date $CurrentDate
```

If I run `c:\shares\boot\UpdateTime.ps1` the time is updated as desired.

I then created a scheduled task:

```
schtasks /create /tn "Update Time Script" /tr C:\shares\boot\UpdateTime.ps1 /sc onstart /ru SYSTEM
```

If I set the time to an incorrect value and reboot, the time is not changed after booted up. Also, If I try to run the sheduled task on demand:

```
schtasks /run /tn "Update Time Script"
```

I get the following response, but the time is not updated:

```
SUCCESS: Attempted to run the scheduled task "Update Time Script".
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Resolved: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/35ed8b44-182f-473d-bd77-c087ab7b72d8/windows-iot-scheduled-task-not-running?forum=WindowsIoT#35ed8b44-182f-473d-bd77-c087ab7b72d8

Comment: Need to call .bat file from scheduled task that in turns calls the powershell script file. schtasks.exe cannot directly call powershell script.